# How to add and use an Enum Case as a Protocol Type Requirement?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, functional-programming, protocols

**Context**

I have multiple `Enums` conforming to a specific `Protocol`. I now would like to define a `Custom Case` for each of these `Enums` and use this `Requirement` for checking for `Equality`.
However, I get the following `Compiler Error`:

> 'var' binding pattern cannot appear in an expression

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component {
    // I read that you can use this Syntax for requiring Enum Cases -> It is working!
    static var default: Self { get }
    static func custom(value: Int) -> Self

    var customValue: Int? { get }
}

extension Component {
    var customValue: Int? {
        guard case .custom(let value) = self else { return nil } // Compiler Error in this Line.
        return value
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal of not only requiring `Cases` but also working with them and checking for `Equality`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't require protocol conformances to be enum's

```
protocol Component {
    static var `default`: Self { get }
    static func custom(value: Int) -> Self

    var customValue: Int? { get }
}

struct C: Component {
    static var `default`: C {
        return C()
    }

    static func custom(value: Int) -> Self {
        return C()
    }

    var customValue: Int? { 42 }
}

let c = C()
c is Component // true
```

And because you can't require conforming types to be enums you can't switch/case on self in a protocol extension

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation even though it is not what I hoped for.